# Probability question about geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to solve this problem taken from the ninth edition of Probability and Statistical Inference written by Hogg , Tanis and Zimmerman. It is problem 18 of the section 2.3:

[image]

I am not sure if this is correct.

I will use the formula of conditional probability:

[image]

Thus

[image]

P(X>(k+j) and X>k)/P(X>k) = P(X>(k+j))/P(X>k)

As we are working with a geometric distribution,

P(X>(k+j))= q^(k+j) and

P(X>k)= q^k.

Then P(X>(k+j))/P(X>k)= q^(k+j)/q^k= q^j = P(X>j)

[image]

when q is the probability of failure.

What do you think? Is it correct?

***Other question: the authors comment "We sometimes
say that in this situation there has been loss of
memory."***

***What are your ideas about this comment?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Regarding the "loss of memory" comment, the reason is that the property $$\Pr[X > k+j \mid X > k] = \Pr[X > j]$$ can be interpreted as follows:  suppose we have a geometric random variable that counts the number of Bernoulli trials until the first success is observed.  Then, given that we have witnessed more than $k$ trials without a success, the probability that we must wait at least $j$ more trials to observe the first success is equal to the unconditional probability of waiting at least $j$ trials.  In other words, the independent nature of the individual trials intuitively suggests that the "past" behavior should not affect future outcomes.  For example, if you flip a coin repeatedly and you have not observed a head, the probability that the next flip is a head is not any more or less than it would be if you had not flipped the coin previously:  the coin doesn't **remember** what it did before.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you much! Thank you for your teachings!